# Pandas: Obtaining the maximum of a column based on other column values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, calculated-columns

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  date      num
1   2018-03-28  3
1   2018-03-29  1
1   2018-03-30  4
1   2018-04-04  1
2   2018-04-03  1
2   2018-04-04  6
2   2018-04-10  3
2   2018-04-11  4
```

Created by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'date': ['2018-03-28', 
'2018-03-29', '2018-03-30', '2018-04-04', '2018-04-03', '2018-04-04',
'2018-04-10', '2018-04-11'], 'num': [3,1,4,1,1,6,3,4]})
```

What I would like is to create a new column called 'maxnum' that is filled with the maximum value of num per ID for the date that is on that row and all earlier dates. This column would look like this:

```
ID  date    maxnum  num
1   2018-03-28  3   3
1   2018-03-29  3   1
1   2018-03-30  4   4
1   2018-04-04  4   1
2   2018-04-03  1   1
2   2018-04-04  6   6
2   2018-04-10  6   3
2   2018-04-11  6   4
```

Does anyone know how I can program this column correctly and efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cummax` (assuming your dataframe is order by `date` already, if not
run mask lines)

```
#df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
#df=df.sort_values('date')
df.groupby('ID').num.cummax()
Out[258]: 
0    3
1    3
2    4
3    4
4    1
5    6
6    6
7    6
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the function I was looking for.

Comment: @LaurensdeWit happy coding